# how can i copy data from a Hive table into local system?

Tags: hive, hiveql

i have created a table in Hive "sample" and loaded a csv file "sample.txt" into it.

now i need that data from "sample" into my local /opt/zxy/sample.txt.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

[Hortonworks'](http://hortonworks.com) Sandbox lets you do it through its HCatalog menu. Otherwise, the syntax is

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/tmp/c' SELECT a.* FROM b
```

as per [Hive language manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Syntax)

Answer (score 1):

Since your intention is just to copy the entire file from HDFS to your local FS, I would not suggest you to do it through a Hive query, because of the following reasons :

- It'll start a Mapreduce job which will take more time than a normal copy.
- It'll create file(s) with different names(`000000_0, 000001_0 and so on`), which will require you to rename the file manually afterwards.
- You `might` face problem in opening these files as they are without any extension. Your OS would be unable to choose an application to open these files on its own. In such a case you either have to rename the file or manually select an application to open it.

To avoid these problems you could use `HDFS get command` :

```
bin/hadoop fs -get /user/hive/warehouse/sample/sample.txt /opt/zxy/sample.txt
```

Simple n easy. But if you need to copy some selected data, then you have to use a Hive query.

HTH

Comment: Hi, no matter what command i put it shows null. I tried with copyToLocal and  get command. I don't understand this part. why cant we use copyToLocal command to copy from this Hive warehouse into your Local system?

Comment: ]$ hadoop fs -get /user/hive/warehouse/orders1/orders.txt /opt/nancy/orders.txt
get: null

Comment: Are you trying it from a user different from your hadoop user?

Answer (score 1):

I usually run my query directly through Hive on the command line for this kind of thing, and pipe it into the local file like so:

```
hive -e 'select * from sample' > /opt/zxy/sample.txt
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: No, Not really. What is the concept behind this? When I try to copy data from the warehouse, using get command, will it copy or move the data from the warehouse? Why cant we use copyToLocal?

Comment: Both get and copyToLocal are intended for files in HDFS. Although the data in Hive is technically stored as files in HDFS under the hood, it makes sense to extract the data using a Hive query rather than attempting to muck with the internals.

Comment: I must say I'm slightly confused as to why you would want to load a file into Hive from local and then extract the exact same unmodified file to local.

Comment: For example, person A has created a Hive table with million records. I want to analyse the records and do some editing of my own without disturbing the table. So i want to copy to to my local system

Comment: @DrewRose what did you end up going with?

Comment: @LukasVermeer if millions of records, is there a way to cache table with compression?

Answer (score 0):

Readers who are accessing Hive from Windows OS can check out [this script](https://github.com/hive-scripts/hivehoney/blob/master/README.md) on Github.

It's a  Python+paramiko script that extracts Hive data to local Windows OS file-system.